# How do I swap around this formula to get the opposite value?

Tags: math

I'm guessing this is simple but I am having a hard time working this out. The formula I have is this: **(1-x) / 0.20**. x equals between 0.8 and 1. Example:

```
(1-0.8) / 0.20 = 1
(1-0.9) / 0.20 = 0.5
(1-1) / 0.20 = 0
```

This is the code I currently have but I a just trying to make it run in the opposite direction `button.alpha = (1-x) / 0.20)`. How do I solve this and what type of math is this called?

Comment: I’m not 100% certain what you mean when you say you want it to run in the opposite direction? Please could you explain this a bit so I can help. Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister meaning in the first example x is 0.8 instead of the equation equaling 1 in needs to equal 0.

Comment: Ah ok. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it run the other way you can just subtract it from 1.

So...

```
button.alpha = 1 - (1 - x) / 0.2
```

Comment: Wow. That simple. Thank you. Does that part of an equation have a term?

Comment: Haha, happy to help. I have spent a long time in the past trying to work this out too. It’s very easy to think it’s more complicated and then spend ages trying to find a way to do it. I don’t know if it has a term though. But now you know it it’ll make it easier when you need it again in the future. 